# 'orientationchange' doesn't seem to be working in S1

Tags: javascript, salesforce1-app, ipad

Recently started using S1. Developing a web app and trying to listen out for orientation change on iPad.

This works perfectly in full site mode on the iPad

```
function doOnOrientationChange() {
    switch(window.orientation) {  
        case -90:
        case 90:
        alert('landscape');
        break; 
        default:
        alert('portrait');
        break; 
    }
 }

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);

// Initial execution if needed
doOnOrientationChange();
```

But only once on initial page load in the S1 app.

Anyone have any suggestions or advice?

Comment: can you simulate an orientation change with Javascript to verify the event listener is working properly?  could it be a browser-specific issue?

Comment: Has anyone found the solution to this? I've tried catching the orientationchange events through normal javascript and using jQuery Mobile but nothing gets triggered. The Salesforce1 guide doesn't provide anything except for Canvas apps.